# Iterate over all rows in dataframe and check all column values are in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 7 columns and ~5.000 rows. I want to check that all the column values in a row are in my list and if so either add them to a new dataframe OR remove those where all values do not match, i.e. remove *false* rows (w/e is the easiest);

```
for row in df:
   for columns in row:
      if df.iloc[row, column].isin(MyList):
         ...*something*
```

I could imagine that `.apply` and `.all` could be used, but I'm afraid my python skills are limited, any help?

Comment: You could try converting your dataframe to a list, df.values.tolist(), and then comparing row by row. You could then remove the rows with dfList.remove("badValue"). After comparing, convert it back to a dataframe.

Comment: Hi @JeffGruenbaum,
Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself clear...

I want to check for all columns in the row, e.g. if dataframe contains 5 columns I only want to keep the row if all 5 values are in MyList; 

TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

Comment: Could you please provide a sample row and a sample MyList?

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum, thank you for your attention :-) jfaccioni managed to solve it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can solve this by using `apply` with a lambda expression like:

```
df.loc[df.apply(lambda row: all(value in MyList for value in row), axis=1))]
```